# Password-protect a custom rss feed

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, themes, rss

I've created a custom post type and would like to send those posts to FB Instant Articles and Apple News via a RSS feed. I've created a custom RSS feed and need to know what's the best way to make that feed password-protected. The CPT is called limitedrun. The feed URL is domain.com/?feed=ltdrun and the RSS template is called rss-ltdrun.php

I know there are plugins that do this but it's not what I'm looking for. They password protect the entire site in order to make the RSS feed password-protected. I need the opposite: RSS password-protected and the website open.

Thanks,

Comment: If the custom feed is password protected how will Facebook and Apple read it?

Comment: They allow password-protect feeds.

Comment: so you mean the *basic HTTP authentication*  as the "password-protect" method ?

Comment: yes. Add authentication to RSS feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it turns out Apple News doesn't accept password-protected RSS feeds. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I would consider this not really a typical WP question – maybe you should ask over at http://unix.stackexchange.com – but maybe this could already help anyways:

If you have access to the *server config* and you know the *IP address* of FB Instant Articles and Apple News you could for example block everybody from accessing your feed – but allow FB Instant Articles and Apple News to access it – with something similar to this:

```
<Location /feed>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 1.1.1.1
</Location>
```

…as answered on [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219353/how-to-deny-access-for-virtual-directories-in-htaccess-for-all-ip-and-accep-fo)  (**this will however NOT work in .htaccess**)